# How can I find and read Alpha News?

Tags: evangelism, resource-request, united-kingdom

The originators of the *Alpha Course* published a newsletter called *Alpha News*, which I have seen cited a few times.

Is there a way to track down back copies of *Alpha News?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found several options.  First, a few issues from the various editions are available online at issuu.com; for example:

- [Jan–Mar 2010](https://issuu.com/alpha-international/docs/anint49jan-mar10)
- [July 2010](https://issuu.com/alpha-international/docs/alphanews_july2010)
- [November 2010](https://issuu.com/alpha-international/docs/anuk51nov2010)

Individual issues of the periodical can sometimes be found for purchase on online auction sites, such as [ebay.com](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=alpha+news&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.X%22alpha+news%22.TRS0&_nkw=%22alpha+news%22&_sacat=0).

And finally, some libraries carry the periodical.  [WorldCat.org](https://www.worldcat.org/search?qt=worldcat_org_all&q=%22alpha+news%22) can be helpful in this regard, though not all libraries with the periodical are listed in the same entry.  [This entry](https://www.worldcat.org/title/alpha-news-keeping-church-leaders-informed-about-the-alpha-course/oclc/499270024&referer=brief_results) lists the National Library of Scotland and the University of Oxford, while [this one](https://www.worldcat.org/title/alpha-news/oclc/49954956&referer=brief_results) lists the University of Cambridge.